# How can I add values in a specific column for every row in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

I am a new bee in the world of wpf programming this is my first ever post here. I have been learning a lot through the stackoverflow platform (thanks to each and every individual here). My current problem is making me bang my head on a wall as I am not able to find a solution for it.
I am doing a project in which I populate a datagrid from an oracle query result using data set as ItemsSource of the datagrid.
It works fine but the problem is, I want to have an "**additional column**"  in my datagrid (in other words I want to add a column manually). This column is not being populated by the dataset. Instead, I want to add/insert values in the manually added column based on one of the auto-populated column.

For example: if I have a value "**A6**" in column1, the manually added column should display "**Actuator**" in the correspondent cell.
Please help me with any possible solution you know. I'd be grateful!!
Idk if my question made any sense or is it too broad. Bear with me if you can't understand anything and feel free to ask. Thank you.

My XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" IsReadOnly="True" 
                    SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Single"                               
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Width="985" Margin="1,5,0,0"
                    CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowHeight="30"
                    CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" ColumnHeaderHeight="30" ColumnWidth="*">
```

My Codebehind:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT this, that, these, FROM table "
                                                     + "WHERE somecolumn=:somecolumn", connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleParameter parm = new OracleParameter();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("somecolumn", input.Text);
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(); 
            oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
            oda.Fill(ds, "table");
            datagrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["table"].DefaultView;
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn(); //here I am able to add the column to the datagrid but not able to insert values in this column             
            datagrid1.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: Mh, for me it looks like you creating a column but you do not add it to the "bound" dataset - somebody corret me if I am wrong, but did you try to add this column to your `ds`? Then you should be able to go through row[x].column["..."] and set the value, no?

Comment: Looks like your code is incomplete. `//here I am able to add the column to the datagrid but not able to insert values in this column` <- You did not add the column yet, you just created it. Can you provide the whole code-block?

Comment: yes I am not adding the column to the "bound" dataset because I have no idea about it. Can you show it with code example ? @TripleEEE

Comment: oh yes I missed out on that!
The last line of the code is:
datagrid1.Columns.Add(column);
I edited the code @Dr.Coconut

Comment: Where do the values you want to insert come from? Not from the SQL i assume. How did you try to insert them?

Comment: I guess the Problem is, that you add the Column to you datagrid. But you got the itemssource defined before. 
You should add the Column to your datatable. Then you bind the new DefaultView to your ItemsSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try it this way:

```
//...
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
oda.Fill(ds, "table");
var table = ds.Tables["table"];
table.Columns.Add("Columnname",typeof(string));
table.Columns["Columname"].DefaultValue = "Actuator";
datagrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

If you want to set rows different you can go like this:

```
table.Rows[0]["Columnname"] = "somewhat";
```

Hope this helps after we discuessed in comments.

Comment: BANG ON!!!! MATE, you made my day!! I can't thank you enough. 
You're absolutely correct, I am adding the new column to the datagrid instead of adding it to the dataset. 
It works. Thanks a lot once again :))

Comment: @Zak29 fine, I could help you :) Good look with your project now :))